# Poison warnings for Lupinus perennis and Consolida ambigua seeds

Tags: flowers, poisons

I was shopping for seeds online and saw a flower seed mix which looked appealing: [Butterfly and Hummingbird Mix](https://www.johnnyseeds.com/flowers/flower-collections-and-mixes/butterfly-and-hummingbird-mix-flower-seed-1738.11.html). It has a poison warning which gave me pause. I'm not much of a gardener so I don't know how serious this is. I bought them anyway as I have no children or pets in the household but then I wondered if I would be murdering the squirrels or something . . .

Is this warning just a "don't do stupid stuff" legal disclaimer or do I need to be concerned about what I may plant nearby which *may* be edible (e.g. cucumbers, etc.) or about putting out bird feeders (aka "squirrel feeders")?

[image]

Comment: Many other plants and seeds are toxic at some level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a dog that likes to eat plants (some do, I've been told) or raise sheep, goats, or cows, then I wouldn't worry about the plants - just don't eat any parts of them. *C. ambigua* is sometimes considered a medicinal herb, as it has been used externally as a lice killer, and L. perennis has been known to kill sheep. *Lupinus polyphylla* is another poisonous lupine often crossed to create garden hybrids, yet I've never heard of it causing any problems.

For more information lupines, you can go to the [FDA's fact sheet on lupines](https://www.cfsanappsexternal.fda.gov/scripts/plantox/detail.cfm?id=1344); there is a fact sheet on C. ambigua, too, but I couldn't access it. [Here's the link](http://www.ars-grin.gov/cgi-bin/npgs/html/taxon.pl?105348); perhaps you'll have better luck.

Comment: thanks! (but what about the squirrels!!!??  )

Comment: I don't think squirrels eat either of these seeds. I grow larkspurs and delphiniums, plus baptisia (a lupine cousin), and I've never seen squirrels at all interested in either of them.